# How do you define modules for polynomial algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am currently reading [this](http://math0.bnu.edu.cn/%7Eliuym/Book-algebras-and-representations.pdf) book and I try to understand p. 33.

I understand Definition 2.7, but Proposition 2.9. seems weird to me. How is $\alpha : V\to V, \, v\mapsto X\cdot v$ a function from $V$ to $V$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proposition, we assume that $V$ is a $K[X]$-module, which means that we know how polynomials act on vectors. This means that for any $g \in K[X]$, the linear map $V \to V$ defined by $v \mapsto g \cdot v$ is specified. In particular, we're interested in the polynomial is $g = X \in K[X]$, and we define the linear map $\alpha: V \to V$ by it.

---

*Added in response to comments:*

There's a natural correspondence
\begin{align}
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\text{linear maps} \\ 
\alpha: V \to V 
\end{matrix} \right\}
&\longleftrightarrow
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\text{module actions} \\ 
\lambda: K[X] \times V \to V 
\end{matrix} \right\}
\end{align}
which we can spell out explicitly.

Beginning with a linear map $\alpha: V \to V$, we can construct a module action $\lambda: K[X] \times V \to V$ as follows. Define $\lambda(X, v) = \alpha(v)$ for all $v \in V$. This is what we mean by *the action of $X$ is determined by $\alpha$.* Now it extends *uniquely* to a linear action over all of $K[X]$ by
$$
\lambda\biggl( \sum_i c_i X^i,\, v \biggr) 
= \sum_i c_i \,\alpha(v)^i
$$
You can verify that this definition satisfies all of the module axioms.

In the other direction, beginning with a linear action $\lambda: K[X] \times V \to V$, we can construct *uniquely* a linear map $\alpha: V \to V$ by $\alpha = \lambda(X, -)$, in other words,
$$
\alpha(v) = \lambda(X, v)
$$
for all $v \in V$. You can check that this must be a linear map.

It remains to see that these correspondences are mutually inverse. If you want to be really explicit, give names to these bijections, say $F$ goes from left to right and $G$ goes from right to left. Then, we would like to verify that
$$
G\bigl( F(\alpha) \bigr) = \alpha
$$
for any linear $\alpha: V \to V$ and that
$$
F\bigl( G(\lambda) \bigr) = \lambda
$$
for any $\lambda: K[X] \times V \to V$. Can you see how this goes?

Comment: Thanks, I see that. But would'nt $g\cdot v$ be defined in terms of $\alpha$? So we'd have $\alpha : V\to V, v\mapsto g\cdot v:=g(\alpha)(v)$. This seem circular.

Comment: @Analysis There's no circularity here, but the notation is definitely confusing. "$V$ is a $K[X]$-module" means "there is some map $f: K[X] \times V \to V$ satisfying [various axioms]" - but usually we don't bother to name the map $f$ at all, and instead of something clunky like $f(g, v)$, we just write $g\cdot v$: we take it for granted that $f$ is "understood" behind the scenes somewhere. But if we write it out fully, then $\alpha$ is defined to be the map you get when you fix the first entry of $f$ to be $X$, i.e. $\alpha = f(X, -)$.

Comment: *Further thought:* Since $X$ is a particular polynomial, it's no surprise that if we begin with a definition of how all of $K[X]$ acts on $V$, then of course we know how $X$ acts. The surprising part is that the converse is also true! In other words, knowing how $X$ acts on $V$ is **equivalent** to knowing how all of $K[X]$ acts on $V$, since the properties of a module action encode scalars and multiplication via composition of linear maps.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Suppose $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ is a $K[X]$-Module. We have $\alpha(v):=X\cdot v$ - what would $\alpha((1,2,3)^T)$ be? To define $\cdot: K[X]\times V\to V$, we also need a linear map, right? And this linear map isn't $\alpha$. This is still kind of confusing to me.